# Shared libraries cannot be found when building application in Yocto

Tags: yocto

I tried to compile my application with cmake in my Yocto project. My application depends on some static and dynamic libraries. And I added the dependencies in my recipe. I confirmed that all .so and .a have had been installed into recipe-sysroot/usr/lib during building. But some errors still occurs, like,
ld: cannot find -lparson
ld: cannot find -luamqp

And I also observed some wired messages like,
-L/yocto/build_test/tmp/work/armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi/my-app/1.0-r0/git/lib
but there is no git/lib

How can I change the link directory to /usr/lib

```
DEPENDS = "\
        azure-iot-sdk-c \
        openssl \
        zlib \
        curl \
        boost \
        parson \
        gtest \
"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"
B = "${WORKDIR}/build"
```

Comment: Can you confirm lib `uamqp` is installed in sysroot as well?

Comment: yes, libuamqp.so is installed in recipe-sysroot/usr/lib.

Comment: Maybe include your CMakeList and cmake tag to question. Is there also FindXXX.cmake and XXX.pc in sysroot? Do you confirm your recipe also contains inherit cmake?

Comment: yes，inherit cmake

Comment: In the CMakeList file, it defines "link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib)". Is it the reason that causes "-L/yocto/build_test/tmp/work/armv7at2hf-neon-fslc-linux-gnueabi/my-app/1.0-r0/git/lib"

Comment: Finally, I confirmed it caused by the line in my CMakeList.txt, "link_directories(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/lib)".